# unrecognized selector sent to instance in viewcontroller

Tags: ios

hi friends i ma using two view controllers in first view controller i am accessing the appdelegate property and try to seeting it but its througing  an exception

in appdelegate

```
@property(nonatomic,assign)NSString *userdate;
```

in firstview controller

```
AppDelegate *obj=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    obj.userdate=@"abcsde";
```

its througing an exception here

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate setUserdate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x717bae0'
```

Comment: Is the property not declared in the header file by some chance?

Comment: seems like property is not getting synthesized. Although XCode do it for you but you can try synthesizing it manually.

Comment: how to synthesiz it manually